# How to ignore all erroneous statements and execute all good ones in JDBC executeBatch?

Tags: jdbc

I have `java.sql.Statement` with lots of batch statements added with `addBatch`. Executing `executeBatch` will throw `BatchUpdateException` after first statement which violates database constrains and won't execute all remaining statements in batch. Is there any way I can execute all statements in batch ignoring erroneous ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [BatchUpdateException: the batch will not terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724957/batchupdateexception-the-batch-will-not-terminate) for a similar question and answers.

It says that the Batch will terminate the moment an exception is thrown. You can't execute just the good ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution would be to fix the erroneous ones.  What's wrong?  The SQL?  The underlying tables?  The data?

Exceptions are supposed to be "exceptional".  What situation is so common that you're likely to see it more often with this batch?

The exception is telling you that something is amiss.  I would not want to recommend a fix that would allow you to ignore the message.  If there's an exception thrown, that means you have an opportunity to ameliorate its root problem in the catch block.

If you're looping over each statement in the batch, you can catch the exception from each one individually and simply log the error.  Just don't ignore it completely.

But unless you can think of another recovery strategy, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to save all data that were possible to insert, just execute commit, and were saved.

looping over each statement in the batch is not possible, only when you call execute batch, you will get the exception, not on each statement (addbatch), so it is not possible to find exactly where the error is:  you can save part of them, or nothing, you decide (commit or rollback).