# JDBC Batch update

Tags: jdbc

IF i have say 1000 statements in a batch.If one of the command fails to execute properly then will all the remaining commands execute or execution stops at that point itself??

Answer (score 1):

Execution stops at that point. Read this post for a solution/workaround : [BatchUpdateException: the batch will not terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724957/batchupdateexception-the-batch-will-not-terminate)

Comment: Is there any way that despite failure of one command all other command should execute??  Also is there any upper limit on the number of commands i can add in the batch??